Separating two signals
I have a signal coming from a microwave module from the movement of some object. I noticed that the spectrum of this signal is divided into harmonics. I will try to explain in more detail in the pictures below.

This is a graph of the signal envelope for the 11.5-12.5 kHz frequency band. Red is a human signal (I would expect to see it in the 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz band), orange is a car signal (I would expect to see it in the 15.5 kHz-16.5 kHz band), and blue is just noise (when there is no movement).

This is a graph of the signal envelope for the frequency band 12.5-13.5 kHz. From it I see that there is also a signal from human movement (red) with a slightly smaller amplitude and a signal from the movement of the car, but with a much larger amplitude.
Next will be graphs for frequencies of 13.5 kHz-14.5 kHz … 16.5-17.5 kHz.




From these graphs it is clear that the signal from human movement gradually fades, while the signal from machine movement, on the contrary, reaches its maximum, as expected, in the frequency band 15.5 kHz-16.5 kHz.
I also saw that the signal from both the person and the machine spreads over several harmonics of the spectrum with decreasing amplitude. It turns out that the signal from the machine is so large in amplitude that it, penetrating into the band 11.5 kHz-12.5 kHz, is equivalent to the signal from the person.
I wanted to somehow separate these signals (if it is even possible). At first I thought to track the signal in the range of 11.5-12.5 kHz and then see if there is a signal with a large amplitude higher in the spectrum, thus I will understand that this is a signal from the movement of the car. But then I realized that if a person is walking and a car is driving at the same time, I will not be able to separate these signals.
From this I had a question: is it possible to separate these signals at all?

Do you need to actually separate the signals or is it maybe enough to just detect whether it is nothing/person/car/both? How different are the signals involved other than what you have shown? Do you have any signal model knowledge or is all you know the rough distribution of energy over frequencies? Can we assume that these graphs at least always look similar to you plots?

@mateC Yes, it is quite easy to determine what kind of object it is. But as I said, there is a problem if two objects (a person and a car) move at the same time. What I showed are real recorded signals. Later, if necessary, I can add more real signal recordings.

Have you considered using FMCW which can distinguish range and velocity? See these articles from Qasim for a good introduction: https://wirelesspi.com/fmcw-radar-part-1-ranging/

@Dan Boschen Yes, thanks, I'll take a look
